# Why DbContext autometically disposed after every api call in EF Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, repository-pattern, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using  [ Repository & UOW ] Pattern to work with EF Core.

**Problem**

Most of the time, after every single successfully call context is disposed & throw error.

**Extension Method**

```
public static IServiceCollection AddDataAccessConfig<C>(this IServiceCollection services) where C : DbContext
{
    RegisterDataAccess<C>(services);
    return services;
}

private static void RegisterDataAccess<C>(IServiceCollection services) where  C : DbContext
{
    services.TryAddScoped<IUnitOfWork<C>, UnitOfWork<C>>();
}
```

**ConfigureServices**

```
//Register Context           
services.AddDataAccessConfig<MyDbContext>();
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DbCon"));
});

//Register Repository      
services.TryAddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
```

I have tried with bellow code. But no luck

> TryAddTransient

```
services.TryAddTransient<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
```

**Repository Base**

```
protected RepositoryBase(IUnitOfWork<C> unitOfWork)
{
    UnitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    _dbSet = UnitOfWork.GetContext.Set<E>(); // THIS LINE THROW ERROR
}
```

**UOW**

```
public UnitOfWork(C dbcontext)
{
    _dbContext = dbcontext;
}

public C GetContext
{
    get { return _dbContext; }
}
```

**Sample Calling Service**

```
public IActionResult ByUser(string uid, string pwd)
{
    var result = _userRepository.GetValidUser(uid, pwd);

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
    }
    else
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result));
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "after every single call"? Show us the code for that and what problem you are having.

Comment: `using [ Repository & UOW ] Pattern to work with EF Core` <= Why? The type `DbContext` is an implementation of a UoW pattern and the `DbSet<T>` type is an implementation of a Repository pattern. Why re-wrap these types in your own implementation of the same pattern? You are adding nothing of value, just more code and abstractions which makes it hard to read, debug, and use the types as they were meant to be used.

Comment: @ShubhajyotiGhosh What is `GetContext`?

Comment: @Igor: User you are true, but most of the time changing code pattern is a developer headache. They try to flow same code structure, as they did. Hope you understand.

Comment: @DavidG:  'DbContext'  as property

Comment: Yes, but where does it come from? Is it injected? Show more context please, without that, this question is unanswerable.

Comment: @DavidG: Yes it is injected using DI, I only get the same using a property, for a specific reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the lifetime of your `IUserRepository` will not affect the lifetime of the `DbContext`. There's an [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.entityframeworkservicecollectionextensions#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions_AddDbContext__1_IServiceCollection_System_Action_System_IServiceProvider_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_DbContextOptionsBuilder__ServiceLifetime_) of `AddDbContext` that allows you to specify the lifetime of the `DbContext`. e.g.

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DbCon"));
}, ServiceLifetime.Transient);
```

The default `ServiceLifetime.Scoped` only really works well if you're inside an ASP.NET Core application. See [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/4988) for more information.

Comment: A db context as a singleton would be an incredibly bad idea.